# How do I create a fake "Loading..." sequence?

Tags: c

So I want to make text appear that says "Loading" followed by 3 delayed dots, and have them start over again, like:

```
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...
Loading.
```

and so on, but always on the same line.

I looked into the delay function without the `dos.h` file (since I'm using gcc), but I'm not sure how to make the dots disappear and start again from the first one.

Comment: hint: `"\b\b\b   \b\b\b"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things you need.

`\r`, or carriage return, moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

Then normally `stdout` will not display anything until it sees a newline. This is called buffering and it needs to be turned off. You can do this with [`setvbuf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setvbuf.html).

Here's a demonstration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    /* Turn off stdout buffering */
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        /* Clear the current line by moving to the start,
           overwriting it with spaces, and going back to the start.
        */
        printf("\r                                             \r");

        printf("Loading");

        /* Print ... over 3 seconds */
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            sleep(1);
            printf(".");
        }

        sleep(1);
    }

    /* Finish it all up with a newline */
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

There are fancier ways to do this [using the curses library](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/CLanguage/Curses.pdf), but `\r` is enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use '\r' character:

```
while (1) {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        printf("Loading%s\r", i==1 ? "." : i==2 ? "..":"...");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1); /* or whatever */
    }
    printf("%20s\r", " ");
}
```

(Fixed: added `fflush(stdout);`)

Answer (score 0):

The character '\b' moves the cursor back one position. The following sequence gets what you want:

```
printf("Loading.");
while (not done yet) {
   delay
   printf(".");
   delay
   printf(".");
   delay
   printf("\b\b   \b\b"); // erase the last two dots, and move the cursor back again
}
```